# Executing Redis Console commands in c#

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I need to get the "CLIENT LIST" output from redis console to be used in my c# application, is there a way to execute that command with the ConnectionMultiplexer? Or is there a built in method to find that information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CLIENT LIST` is a "server" command, not a "database" command ([as differentiated here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan)), so you need to use `IServer` / `GetServer()` instead of `IDatabase` / `GetDatabase()`. The link shown also shows how to do this. Once you have that: there are `ClientList` and `ClientListAsync` methods that deal with all the parsing into a `ClientInfo` instance.

If it *wasn't* there, then the fallback options would be `IDatabase.Execute[Async]` (to issue an arbitrary raw command) or `IDatabase.ScriptEvaluate[Async]` (to issue Lua script).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for the immediate answer

Comment: according to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache) `CLIENT LIST` is a IDatabase command

Comment: @badaboomskey they are abusing `execute` here; I'm actually very disappointed that they've done that in those docs, especially as azure redis is often clustered. What this means is: they are arbitrarily picking a random server for this (if it works at all). Please trust me here: `client list` is a server-specific command. Not intended to sound boastful, but: my opinion trumps those docs. The docs are either "wrong" or "dangerously misleading" depending on how forgiving you are feeling.

Comment: @badaboomskey I've opened a ticket: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53235