# Executing 'MEMORY STATS' with Redis IDatabase.Execute - unknown command

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I did not find a way to get the memory available using `IServer`, so instead I am trying to do so using `IDatabase.ExecuteAsync("MEMORY STATS")` and then processing the result

In the Redis Console one can write `MEMORY STATS` and get an array output - https://redis.io/commands/memory-stats.

This post says I can use `ExecuteAsync` to pass raw commands - [Executing Redis Console commands in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029963/executing-redis-console-commands-in-c-sharp)

Yet when I do `IDatabase.ExecuteAsync("MEMORY STATS")` I get the following error:

```
"RedisServerException: ERR unknown command `MEMORY STATS`, with args beginning with:".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `IDatabase.ExecuteAsync("MEMORY", "STATS")`.

This is because in reality, [there is a `MEMORY` command](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/5.0.7/src/server.c#L285), and `STATS`, `USAGE`, etc are treated as a first argument. This is so even when it is documented as a single `MEMORY STATS` command.

So, translated to [RESP2](https://redis.io/topics/protocol#sending-commands-to-a-redis-server), the server is expecting two separate strings, not a single string with a space in the middle.